# Java inheritance: Cannot refer to an instance field while explicitly invoking a constructor

Tags: java, inheritance

Given that i have a hierarchy of classes. The parrent class is as below:

```
public class Utils {

    protected Driver driver;

    public Utils() {
        this.driver = new Driver();
    }

    public Utils(Driver driver,String xPath) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.driver.waitForElement(xPath, 2);
    }
```

And the child is:

```
public class SelectRegisteredOwner extends Utils {


    final String newOrUsed = "//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]";


    public SelectRegisteredOwner( Driver driver) {
        super(driver,newOrUsed);
    }}
```

The problem is, in the child class in the line `super(driver,newOrUsed);` it complains with:

```
Cannot refer to an instance field newOrUsed while explicitly invoking a constructor
```

and as a quick fix, it suggest to consider `newOrUsed` as a `static` attribute

Is there anyways to fix this issue without making the attribute static?

Comment: Move the newOrUsed into the constructor (hardcoded)

Comment: I wouldnt have thought so, the class hasnt been constructed so you can't pass the value into `super`.  Given that it is final and assigned a value, I would just make it static.

Comment: or move the variable into the super class

Comment: `newOrUsed` certainly looks like a constant value.  Why would you want each instance to have its own copy instead of just making it static?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the final field `newOrUsed` before the class is initialized. Make it static or move it into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

That field looks like a constant allowing you to identify an element in the UI. I would make it a constant and separate it from your subclass:

```java
public class Utils {

    private Driver driver;  //make them private and expose getters
    private String xPath;

    public Utils() {
        this.driver = new Driver();
    }

    public Utils(Driver driver,String xPath) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.xPath = xPath;
        this.driver.waitForElement(xPath, 2);
    }
   protected Driver getDriver(){...}
   protected Driver getXPath(){...}
}

public class SelectRegisteredOwner extends Utils {
    public SelectRegisteredOwner( Driver driver) {
        super(driver,XPathSelector.NEW_OR_USED);
    }
}

public interface XPathSelector{
    String NEW_OR_USED = "//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the field has a constant value, you can make it `static` as you mentioned. But since your requirement is not to use `static`, I recommend this approach

```
class Utils {

    protected Driver driver;

    public Utils() {
        this(new Driver());
    }

    public Utils(Driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void addXPath(String xPath) {
        this.driver.waitForElement(xPath, 2);
    }
}

class SelectRegisteredOwner extends Utils {

    final String newOrUsed = "//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]";

    public SelectRegisteredOwner(Driver driver) {
        super(driver);
        addXPath(newOrUsed);
    }
}
```

Now, since you have `default` and `overloaded` constructor in `Utils`, that clearly indicates `xPath` is not mandatory.

So, you can leverage a regular method to add that to your `driver` once it is constructed as adding `xPath` is totally within `SelectRegisteredOwner` control.